# Updating Datagridview data using SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I'm having trouble updating data from a data grid view with the use of a button. The text is editable but the changes does not save to the SQLite database. any ideas?

```
    private void ProjectsAdmin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'seniorProjectsDataSet2.DataTable1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.seniorProjectsDataSet2.DataTable1);
    }


    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex != 3)  //ignore header row and any column that doesnt have file name
            return;

        var filename = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

        if (File.Exists(filename))
            Process.Start(filename);

    }



    private void updateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection();
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();

        dataTable1TableAdapter.Adapter.Update(seniorProjectsDataSet.Tables[0]);


        for (int i = 0; i < seniorProjectsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            seniorProjectsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].AcceptChanges();

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem without a Button. In the following code I´ll give you a example how the connection and the update works with a mysql-database (update in runtime):

**CODE**

```
    DataTable dt = null;
    DataGridView dgv1 = null;
```

If the form load you have to set your dt variable to a new datatable:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();



        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select *from try.data ;";
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        dgv1 = new DataGridView();
        dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellEndEdit);
        dgv1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dgv_CellValidating);
        dgv1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dgv1.DataSource = dt;

        this.Controls.Add(dgv1);
    }
```

You have to set two events: CellValidating

```
   private void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            dgv1.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
```

and the CellValidating Event:

```
   private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Eid"] + "";
        string col = dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName;
        string data = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value + "";

        string sql = string.Format("UPDATE `try`.`data` SET `{0}` = '{1}' WHERE Eid = {2};", col, data, id);

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

This aktually works with MySql but in Sql are "Equal" components like the SqlConnection or the SqlCommand... I hope this solve you problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: I understand your solution, but my datagridview is displayed by a binding source with JOINS from 3 different tables. I am going to somehow implement your solution to fit my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. The binding source actually don´t matter for this solution. The code is nearly the same.I hope you can solve the problem with this solution. If it will please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Cogs\\bin\\Release\\db\\my_database_file.db");
SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from [my_table]";
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dta = new DataTable();
SQLiteDataAdapter dataadp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
dataadp.Fill(dta);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dta;
con.Close();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).